# How to extract data from atomic assets ATTRIBUTE_MAP

Tags: eosio-code

Title says it all. I'd like to get data from atomic assets' attribute map.

This is the link to their docs https://github.com/pinknetworkx/atomicassets-contract/wiki/Custom-Types#atomic_attrbiute tried a lot of ways but couldn't get to make it work. Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: did you find out how to do it? thanks!

Comment: I know the data is serialized with the map types so I could count bytes to get the desired value. however a helper method for deserialization would be handy.

Comment: I did this here: https://github.com/liquidapps-io/zeus-sdk/blob/master/boxes/groups/sample/atomictokenpeg/contracts/eos/atomictokenpeg/atomictokenpeg.cpp, you can also ask here https://t.me/atomicdevs

Comment: Hey @kasperTaeymans posted an answer in case you still haven't found a way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot to post an answer to this question when I found it. Here's how:

Assuming I wanted to take the "Rarity" value from an ATTRIBUTE_MAP, this is how I would get it.

`string rarity_value = get<string>(immutable_template_data["rarity"]);`

For further context:
get(ATTRIBUTE_MAP variable[key_name])

Hopefully this was clear enough to anyone who also needed the answer. Please feel free to comment if you need help too, would love to be able to contribute to the community.